# how to get all keys from couchbase?

Tags: python, view, couchbase, bucket

i use python language to get all keys from couchbase, the following is my code;

```
function(doc, meta){
    emit(null, meta.id);
}
```

this is view in "namedb" bucket;

```
from couchbase import Couchbase
db = Couchbase.connect(bucket="namedb", host="192.168.1.170", port=8091)
name = 'key'
view = 'all'
skip=0
limit = 10000
fd = open("name.txt", "a", 0)
num = 1000000
while skip < num:
    result = db.query(name, view, use_devmode = False, limit = limit, skip = skip)
    for row in result:
        fd.write(row.value + '\n')
    skip += limit
fd.close()
```

there have 1000000 documents in this bucket, and when skip = 210000, result variable will get a empty result;

i excute this program many times; when skip = 210000, db.query() function always return empty result;  how can i resolve it? how can i get all keys in this bucket? thank you

Comment: Are you getting an exception or error, or is the iterator just not yielding any rows

Comment: Also, consider passing the `streaming` option to the `query()` method (http://pythonhosted.org/couchbase/api/views.html#couchbase.views.iterator.View; the `query()` method just wraps the additional keyword arguments in a `View` object, if one isn't explicitly passed).

Using the `streaming` option, rows are returned incrementally to the client, so that you can start processing the results as soon as any arrive, rather than waiting for the entire resultset to buffer.

Comment: It is not necessary to emit the id. It is already emitted as part of the view row. Emit (null, null) instead.  Also, have you tried querying the CB API directly (e.g. in-browser), and what is the result?

Comment: think you for your help. i have other questions, and hope to get your help,if there has one bilion documents in a bucket, and i want to get all keys, so i create a query view(just like you say emit(null,null)), but it will spend a long time; i think it is not necessary to waste so much time because the query view have no any filter logic;