# how to get all the key from one bucket in couchbase?

Tags: python, couchbase

Using Python SDK, could not find how to get all the keys from one bucket
in couchbase.

Docs reference:

```
http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client-2.2.0/api/couchbase.html#item-api-methods
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/tree/master/examples
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040667/how-to-get-all-keys-from-couchbase
```

Is there a simple way to get all the keys ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little concerned as to why you would want every single key. The number of documents can get very large, and I can't think of a good reason to want every single key.

That being said, here are a couple of ways to do it in Couchbase:

1. N1QL. First, create a primary index (`CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON bucketname`), then select the keys: `SELECT META().id FROM bucketname`; In Python, you can use `N1QLQuery` and `N1QLRequest` to execute these.
2. Create a map/reduce view index. Literally the default map function when you create a new map/reduce view index is exactly that: `function (doc, meta) { emit(meta.id, null); }`. In Python, [use the `View` class](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client-2.3.5/api/views.html).

You don't need Python to do these things, by the way, but you can use it if you'd like. Check out the documentation for the [Couchbase Python SDK](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/python/start-using-sdk.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a little concerned as to why you would want every single key. The number of documents can get very large, and I can't think of a good reason to want every single key.

There is a document for every customer with the key being the username  for the customer. That username is only held as a one-way hash (along with the password) for authentication.  It is not stored in its original form or in a form from which the original can be recovered. It's not feasible to ask the 100 million customers to provide their userids. This came from an actual customer on #seteam.